# Android: How to put each tuple returned from a SQL database as text on a button?

Tags: android, mysql, button, android-button

so I am making this app which currently connects to an external SQL database with a list of item names (I use php and json for this), and it displays these names as a textView. I followed this tutorial to learn this:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Soj22OMc98

However, what I really want to do is have the app have a button for EACH of the item names. Is there a way to make my app such that for each item name it pulls from the database, it creates a button, with the item's name as the text on that button?

Answer (score 0):

This is very do-able. For each item name retrieved from your database, you need to programatically create a button and set the text attribute to the name.

```
    Button b = new Button();
    b.setText(insertNameHere);
```

Of course you also need to set the position of these buttons as well. This resource gives a good tutorial for creating buttons in this way: [Tutorial](http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html)